# java GUI multiple buttons output display error?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am beginner in Java. This is my first project.
The GUI of the code keeps changing every time I run the code.
Sometimes output doesn't even load completely.
This is the code for just initializing a chess board 8X8 jbuttons.

I have put down the images do checkout the hyperlinks below.

Is there any solution that shows the same output every time the code executes?

```
    package chess;
    import game.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class board{
    static JButton [][] spots =new  JButton [8][8];
    public static void main(String[] args){
    board b =new board();
    b.initializeboard(spots);
    }


    public void initializeboard(JButton [][] spots){
    JFrame f = new JFrame("CHESS");
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(800,800);

    GridLayout layout =new GridLayout(8,8,1,1); 
    f.setLayout(layout);

    for(int ver=0;ver<8;ver++){
      for(int hor=0;hor<8;hor++){
           JButton button = new JButton();
           if((ver+hor)%2==0){
                    button.setBackground(Color.WHITE); }
           else{
                    button.setBackground(new Color(255,205,51)); }
           pieces p =new pieces();
           spots[ver][hor] = button;
           p.setButton(button);
           f.add(button);
           }
              }
                  } //initialize board
                       }  // close board
```

[Improper Execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDsS5.png)

[Correct Execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwZBe.png)

[Incomplete Execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXECk.png)

Comment: Hi please next time open your question with some short and clear descriptions about your problems. Don't start with source code. I'm not a sales person but all I know is in marketing you start with communication first. And I know it might sound ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am beginner in Java.

First of all, class names SHOULD start with an upper case character. Have you even seen a class in the JDK that does not start with an upper case character? Learn by example from the code in your text book or tutorial.

> Is there any solution that shows the same output every time the code executes?

All components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.

When the frame is made visible the layout manager is invoked and the components are given a size/location. If you add components to a visible panel, then you need to invoke `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the panel to make sure the layout manager is invoked.

Must admit I'm not sure why you get this random behaviour. Some components are getting a size/location and other are not even though the layout manager is not invoked.

I would suggest you restructure your code something like:

```
JPanel chessboard = new JPanel( new GridLayout(8, 8,  1, 1) );
// add buttons to the panel

JFrame frame = new JFrame("CHESS")
frame.add(chessboard, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
frame.setVisible( true );
```

Other comments:

1. Don't set the size of the frame. Using 800 x 800 will not make each button 100 x 100. The frame size also include the title bar and borders, so each button size will be less than you expect.

Instead you can create a variable outside of your loops:

```
Dimension buttonSize = new Dimension(100, 100)
```

Then when you create the button you use:

```
button.setPreferredSize( buttonSize );
```

Now when pack() method is invoked is will size the frame at the preferred size of all the components added to the frame.

2. All Swing components should be create on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial [How to Make Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html). The `FrameDemo.java` code shows you one way to structure your class so that the `invokeLater(…)` method is used to make sure code executes on the EDT.
3. Don't make your variables static. This indicates incorrect class design. Check out the `MenuLook.java` example found in [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for a slightly different design where your `ChessBoard` becomes a component created in another class. You can then define your instance variables in that class.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the help. But just to be sure do i have to revalidate() every time i change something like when a button is clicked and and the chess peice is moved ?

Comment: Generally you only need the revalidate() when you add/remove components from a panel of a visible GUI. Don't know how your game is designed. but typically you don't move the button. You change the Icon that is displayed in the button. In this case Swing is smart enough to revalidate() and repaint() the component when you change any of its properties.

Comment: Thanks . btw i wasnt going to move the button i was just going to move the label over the button using ActionListener() of that button.